# Finding minimal number of del/insert/change to transform string X(len=m) to string Y(len=n)

Tags: string, replace, lcs

I’ve read and pretty much understood the algorithm to solve this problem using only insert/delete actions, which completes the task in `O(n * m)`

I was thinking; if we were also able to change(replace) a character in the process, how would that affect/change the algorithm?

Would it matter in any sort of way, by running time / space requirements?

Thanks!

Comment: The standard edit distance problem allows changing a character.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I dont seem to understand your point

Comment: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Edit_distance#/Formal_definition_and_properties  I mean the standard problem allows all three operations you listed and hence you can just look up the corresponding solution